# using discriminator for subclasses of subclasses

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Problem seems pretty generic, but I am new to fluentnhibernate and all my searches did not turn up anything useful.

I have a class hierarchy similar to this one:

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string GivenName { get; set; }
    public virtual string FamilyName { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    public virtual string WhoAmI { get { return "I am just an Employee"; } protected set { } }
} 

public class Boss : Employee
{
    public override string WhoAmI { get { return "I am the boss."; } protected set { } }
}
```

I.e. one base class and two subclasses (one derived from the other). The subclasses have the same signature, but the base class has not.

The mapping below will put all information about the instances of the three classes into the same table:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.GivenName);
        Map(x => x.FamilyName);
        DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("type");
    }
}

public class EmployeeMap : SubclassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.WhoAmI);
    }
}

public class BossMap : SubclassMap<Boss>
{
    public BossMap()
    {
    }
}
```

Leaving out the DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn will generate three tables:

```
public class PersonMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.GivenName);
        Map(x => x.FamilyName);
    }
}

public class EmployeeMap : SubclassMap<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.WhoAmI);
    }
}

public class BossMap : SubclassMap<Boss>
{
    public BossMap()
    {
    }
}
```

My question: Is it possible (in fluentnhibernate) to map these classes into exactly two tables, i.e. to have

- one Person table that holds all the properties derived from the Person class, and
- an Employee table that holds all the properties derived from the Employee class, plus a discriminator that discriminates between normal Employees and Bosses?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply alias BossMap to EmployeeMap:

```
public class BossMap : EmployeeMap {}
```

you should get the mapping that you need.

Comment: Not really. All I seem to be getting are FluentConfigurationExceptions, both with DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn in PersonMap and without.

Comment: What is the exception message?

Comment: Innermost exception was "Duplicate class/entity mapping Examples.FirstProject.Entities.Employee"

Comment: Have you tried simply subclassing the `Boss` class without the `BossMap`?  Since there is no distinction in the DB structure between the two classes you may not need the mapping class.

Comment: That does not seem to help either. Just "No persister for: Examples.FirstProject.Entities.Boss". Even if I cast my Bosses to Employees.